# How to publish events to multiple receivers using ServiceStack

Tags: events, servicestack

I've been using ServiceStack to communicate between systems and was wondering if it's also possible to using ServiceStack in a way that Events can be published to which 0 to N other can subscribe.

It should also work in a async/disonnected way that if the Event would be published when the subscriber is temporarily down/unavailable the Event would still be delivered. Can this be achieved using ServiceStack, and if so, what's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack supports notifying [multiple subscribers with Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server) which supports both JavaScript or [C#/.NET Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client).

Another option to implement Pub/Sub messaging is to use the native [Pub/Sub library support in Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server).

But neither of these supports **durable Pub/Sub**, i.e. clients don't receive messages sent whilst they're not connected. The MQ Support in [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ) and [RedisMQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) does support durable messaging but they're not Pub/Sub, i.e they're just **1:1** Message Queues.